# JPopupMenu arrows for up and down when showing a lot of information

Tags: java, swing

I am using JPopup menu to implement an autocomplete model in java. everything works fine but the problem is when showing a lot of data that could be irritating. How could I implement arrows for up and down and limit the number of items to let's say to 5?

Is there any better approach for autocomplete model?

[image: example of too many irritating result set]

Comment: 1. voting to close too, 2. there are ( autocomplete model in java.) bunch of attepts for autocomplete JComboBox, 3. and JComboBox has (to limit the number of items to lets say 5.) method for that implemented in API, 4. Iwoudn't be to use JPopup, use JComboBox instead, thats easier and quite comfortable

Answer (score 1):

You essentially want what a JComboBox does.  See [BasicComboPopup](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicComboPopup.html) What you would basically do is wrap your popup in a JScrollPane

Answer (score 0):

Check out Darryl's [Menu Scroller](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/02/01/menu-scroller/).

It has a few features you can customize:

1. the number of items to display
2. fixed items at the top/bottom
3. scrolling speed